# Getting A List of System Processes in Java Using Hyperic SIGAR

Tags: java, exception, process, sigar, intermittent

I am trying to figure out how to get a `list` of system processes using `Hyperic SIGAR`. This is what I have so far:

```
import org.hyperic.sigar.Humidor;
import org.hyperic.sigar.ProcExe;
import org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException;
import org.hyperic.sigar.SigarProxy;

public class ProcessReader 
{
    Humidor h; 
    public ProcessReader()
    {
        h = Humidor.getInstance(); 
    }
    public void printProcessList()
    {
        SigarProxy sp = h.getSigar();
        try 
        {
            long[] pidList = sp.getProcList();
            for(int i=0; i<pidList.length; i++)
            {
                ProcExe temp = sp.getProcExe(pidList[i]); 
                String exeName = temp.getName(); 
                System.out.println(pidList[i] + " " + exeName); 
            }
        } catch (SigarException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

However, this just ends up throwing a SIGAR exception after a seemingly-arbitrary number of iterations. For example, once, I got this:

```
1313 /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

1311 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/mdworker
```

and then it threw a `Sigar Exception` for an invalid argument at the line:

`ProcExe temp = sp.getProcExe(pidList[i]);`

Sometimes, it runs for more than two iterations. Sometimes, it runs for less than two iterations. I'm not quite sure what's going on, and the `SIGAR` documentation doesn't seem to be very helpful. When I wanted to access the CPU and RAM usage information, I used a similar method of getting a `Humidor`, getting a `SIGARProxy` from it, and then getting the information objects (CPU and Mem, respectively) from the `SIGARProxy`. However, doing this for the system processes doesn't seem to be working very well. How am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can Check the class "Ps" under the org.hyperic.sigar.cmd package delivered along with the Sigar package.  It lists all the processes running on the system.
I am sure you can manipulate it to get the system processes as well. You can filter the output it with these options:

1. org/hyperic/sigar/cmd/Ps "CredName.User.eq=$USER"

or if you want to search particualr process use this:

1. org/hyperic/sigar/cmd/Ps "State.Name.eq=sshd"